# Use Variable in a select statement in a Function

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to declare a variable from another variable that was already declared in a function?

Example of what I am expecting below..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertRecord
(
    a varchar (100),
    b varchar(100),
    c varchar(100)

) 
RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE

orgId := (select id from org)

projectId := select id from project where orgId = orgId

BEGIN

return projectId;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please show the complete code of the function.

Comment: Done - I just want to know if I can do orgId = orgId or do I have to do Where orgId = (select id from org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare the variables. And rename the orgId to avoid ambiguity with the column name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertRecord 
(
a varchar (100),
b varchar(100),
c varchar(100)

) 
RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE

orgId_var integer;
projectId varchar;


BEGIN

orgId_var := (select id from org limit 1);

projectId := (select id from project where orgId = orgId_var);

return projectId;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I was using the same name the entire time..no wonder it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want to use a join instead?  Something along these lines (but with more filters added so as not to return multiple rows):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertRecord(
    a varchar (100),
    b varchar(100),
    c varchar(100)
)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$

DECLARE

    v_project_id project.id%TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT p.id
      INTO v_project_id
      FROM project p
      JOIN org o ON (o.id = p.org_id);

    RETURN v_project_id;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```